# TextView text color in complex ListView item differs across devices

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView, and a custom item layout which consists only of a TextView and Button. The actual ListView is working fine, but it appears differently on different devices that I test on.

On my Android 8.0 device the text is dark grey, but on my 6.0 device the text is light grey and is barely visible against the white background of my Activity. Additionally, the Button colors are reversed on that device too, with dark text on a light button in 8.0, and the other way round on 6.0.

```
<RelativeLayout            
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cell_peer"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_peer_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_call_peer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Call"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.FriendsListActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="Call a friend"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    ></activity>
```

I can fix the text contrast issue easy enough by setting `android:textColor="@color/color_callable_peer_name"` on the TextView, but my question is: Why does this text default to different colors on different platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Because you can do that easily.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == ......Marshmallow){
            // set text color you wanted}
        else
        {
            //set text color you wanted
        }
    }     
}
```

in your xml file use MyTextView instead TextView.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question of "Why does this text default to different colors on different platforms?". I'm not trying to find a way to set it different colors on different platforms, I want it to be the same on all, and want to know what I'm doing wrong